# JMeter response times do not match manually timed

Tags: jmeter

I'm running some JMeter tests that create applications, upload documents etc. I know the tests are passing as the documents and applications are being created. I can verify this. However what is interesting is the response times in JMeter are significantly slower than when I manually time the site while running the load test. Page load time in JMeter average around 20 seconds when in reality it's only taking about 5 seconds when hand time. Any ideas what could be causing this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Several assumptions:

1. It might be connected with [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), main HTML response is relatively small and fast, but it triggers downloading of so called "embedded resources": images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. Real browsers download these resources only once and JMeter is requesting them each time it requests the page. Try adding [HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to your Test Plan and see if it resolves your issue. And [clean your browsing data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox) before manually assessing the website responsiveness as JMeter establishes a new session so your browser needs to be "fresh" as well.
2. Manual check is not something you should be normally doing as it is not very possible to apply pass/fail criteria so it might be better to consider using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework
3. Make sure that JMeter is properly configured for high loads as if it lacks resources or its configuration is not optimal it will still work but work kind of slowly causing false-negative results so you need to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
4. If you're using [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) make sure to not to include the time taken by pre/postprocessors and timers into the transaction, well-behaved JMeter test should use think times but shouldn't include them into response times

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal, the issue could be explained by that fact that requests (JMeter threads) might be getting queued at the client machine(s), while the manual requests are executed on a different environment. This [link](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-os-load-average-and-run-queue-blocked-queue-in-terms-of-cpu-utilization-in-linux/) shows more information about this issue. Also, I've seen cases where the **load balancer** is the bottleneck.